# SonataMediaBundle - S3 AWS: 'The configured bucket "my-bucket" does not exist

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to configure the AWS s3 filesystem on my Sonata-Project, but I always get the following error:

> The configured bucket "my-bucket" does not exist.

My `sonata_media.yml`:

```
cdn:
    server:
        path: http://%s3_bucket_name%.s3-website-%s3_region%.amazonaws.com

providers:
    image:
        filesystem: sonata.media.filesystem.s3
    file:
        resizer:    false
        allowed_extensions: ['pdf']
        allowed_mime_types: ['application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf']


filesystem:
    s3:
        bucket: %s3_bucket_name%
        accessKey: %s3_access_key%
        secretKey: %s3_secret_key%
        region: %s3_region%
```

I added the following parameters to my parameters.yml:

```
s3_bucket_name: my-bucket
s3_region: eu-central-1
s3_access_key: MY_ACCESS_KEY
s3_secret_key: MY_SECRET_KEY
```

At the moment I use this library:

> ```
>     "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.8.10"
> ```
>
> (With the latest versions I got an error with the s3_region parameter.)

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think I don't have to say the bucket IS there.

Does anyone have an idea, what the problem is?

Comment: What is the version of sonata-media that you use ? My aws integration works fine with :
"sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.x-dev#b3b26a2",
 "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~2.7"

I use the 2.3 branch with the commit id that references the integration of the new sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ran in this issue too and spent about 3 hours to fix it.

## TL; DR

I am pretty sure you used `aws-sdk-php 3` so you have to switch your configuration to use this one:

```
services:
    acme.aws_s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [Aws\S3\S3Client, 'factory']
        arguments:
            -
                version: latest
                region: %amazon_s3.region%
                credentials:
                    key: %amazon_s3.key%
                    secret: %amazon_s3.secret%
```

instead of this one:

```
services:
    acme.aws_s3.client:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory: [Aws\S3\S3Client, 'factory']
        arguments:
            -
                key: %amazon_s3.key%
                secret: %amazon_s3.secret%
                region: %amazon_s3.region%
```

as described [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/adapters/awss3.md). So you always connected to AWS without any credentials.

## Configure `knp_gaufrette` in a correct way

### 1) Create a IAM user

Don't use your root access key and access secret to interact with Amazon S3. Create a new account with the access type "Programmatic access" to explicit allow the interaction with a single bucket. I called my user `s3-bucket-staging` and Amazon gave it the id `arn:aws:iam::REMOVED:user/s3-bucket-staging`.

[image: aws-create-account]

You don't have to add a group or attach any policies. **Make sure you save the generated Access key ID and Secret access key since this is the only chance you have to do so.**

### 2) Edit your bucket policy

So for a very basic bucket with global read but no list permission (so people can access single files but not the list of all files) you can then add the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1489062408719",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::REMOVED:user/s3-bucket-staging"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::REMOVED:user/s3-bucket-staging"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

See also:

- [Specifying a Principal in a Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html)
- [IAM Policy Elements: Principal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)
- [Providing Credentials to the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html)
- [Request via aws cli client works fine but using PHP SDK fails with 403 clientError Forbidden](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/764)

Comment: What does `REMOVED` refer to here? Is that the name of the user account you created for s3?

Comment: Yes, this is basically the aws user id (the id is represented by the whole string you can copy from aws: `arn:aws:iam::REMOVED:user`)