# S3 Bucket Policy by domain returning 403 Forbidden for object requests in Symfony app with Varnish

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, varnish, liipimaginebundle, gaufrette

I have a PHP+Symfony web app behind Varnish with sites assets (i.e. images, video) stored in an S3 bucket. I want to restrict access to these assets using an s3 bucket policy by referrer. The policy I applied to the bucket is (with identifying info removed):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referrer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get & put requests referred by test.com.",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://www.test.com/*",
                    "https://test.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referrer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "https://www.test.com/*",
                    "https://test.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I've compared my policy against multiple SO and other forum posts and it seems correct. If I apply this policy to my bucket, requests for each asset on any page of my site appears broken with response status 403 Forbidden:

```
Request URL:http://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/site-assets/img/film-icon.svg
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:54.231.131.120:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

If I remove the policy it works again. So the policy is taking effect, its just not allowing my own domain (in this sample code, test.com) access to the assets but its defined as "allow" in the bucket policy.

In case it is relevant, my web app is using KnpGaufrette as a filesystem which is configured to use s3 and this in turn is being used by LiipImagineBundle to handle any image processing where needed. My server also has Varnish 4 installed in front of the web server to provide caching (I have tried clearing varnish cache, restarting varnish and apache after applying the policy in case).

If you can help, that would be great.

Comment: Ran into a similar issue, maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963428/sonatamediabundle-s3-aws-the-configured-bucket-my-bucket-does-not-exist/47201223#47201223

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen Thanks. I will give it a try when I get a moment.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem, you just have to add

```
   "aws:Referer": [
    "https://www.test.com/*",
     "https://test.com/*",
 "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/*"
    ]
```

to your Bucket policy (Replace URL with your region and bucket name), and it will start working.

Hope it will help.

Comment: would that be something like this:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referrer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "aws:Referer": [
                "https://www.test.com/*",
                 "https://test.com/*",
             "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/*"
                ]
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. Seems that the section deny policy denies my own url from accessing the assets on s3 but it should only be denying urls outside of mine.

If I try without the deny, I can access my assets but this is a pointless policy as its the same as having no policy.

Answer (score 0):

In response, you should able to see aws Referer url.
If its different than the list of urls you mentioned in "aws:Referer" then add that.